# Convert a string to json format

Tags: java

I am having a string like

```
request_method=GET, domain=com.tables.com, url=//search.do?table-id=549499, original_url=, remote_host=198.192.0.3, user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36", edgescape="", akamai_bot=""
```

I cannot change the value as its coming from some configurations. I want to convert the value to JSON format like below.

```
request_method : GET, domain : com.tables.com, url : //search.do?table-id=549499, original_url :, remote_host : 198.192.0.3, user_agent : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36", edgescape : "", akamai_bot : ""
```

Is there any way without manually splitting based on the comma and doing it ?

Comment: is that really a JSON format?

Comment: You have to do manual transitions with replaceAll or may be split .

Comment: Don't understand your JSON. Did you try using JSONParser?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all these values in a presenter class.

Firstly create a presenter class

```
Public class DataPresenter
{
    private String requestMethod;
    private String domain;
    private String url;

    public String getRequestMethod()
    {
    return requestMethod;
    }

    public String setRequestMethod(String requestMethod)
    {
    this.requestMethod = requestMethod;
    }

    ................ so on.
}
```

Now you can create the object of DataPresenter Class and set your data in it.

```
DataPresenter dataPresenter = new DataPresenter();
dataPresenter.setRequestMethod = 'GET';
dataPresenter.setDomain = 'domain';
dataPresenter.setURL = 'http://url';
```

Now parse the above object into json string using gson library.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(dataPresenter);
```

And I think that is what you required. :)